# Does plovr support the latest closure library?

Tags: google-closure-library, google-closure-templates, plovr

I was using plovr as closure compiler for the latest google closure library, but it think it plays nicely. Why is this so?

Link=http://plovr.com/docs.html

Thanks in advance for the help,

Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you update the library, you would also need to update the compiler, as they're designed to work together. Getting a new compiler release to work with Plovr is non-trivial since it makes use of its internals and thus Plovr itself must be recompiled. While Plovr supports pointing to a custom Closure Library checkout, there have been enough changes (e.g. dependency, type system, module declarations) in Closure to make Plovr's stale compiler incompatible with recent library releases.

Here are a couple blocking issues in supporting more recent editions of the Library:

- [#162: Dependency analysis is outdated](https://github.com/bolinfest/plovr/issues/162)
- [#160: Generation logic of deps.js is outdated](https://github.com/bolinfest/plovr/issues/160)

This is particularly striking as new namespaces in the Library make use of the `goog.module`-style declaration.

Comment: After Mr Bolin focused on other projects (chiefly, Facebook's [Buck](https://buckbuild.com/)), the driving force behind the maintenance of Plovr were the folks at Medium. From [recent comments](https://github.com/bolinfest/plovr/issues/143#issuecomment-352082582) it seems that they're looking at Bazel+Closure instead of Plovr. I wouldn't bank on Plovr for new Google Closure projects.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that I have contributed to Plovr last week to be able to support the latest version. However, since medium took over the NPM package I created a fork that I like to keep updated. Google Closure Compiler and Google Closure Library are both excellent tools. Plovr is also.

Please take a look over at: https://github.com/Plovr/Plovr-build/packages/36644 which is the npm package hosted at github packages. I plan to add this later to npm too. It works with the current latest release of closure (v20190929, released 14 days ago as of writing this post)